# $L^{\infty}$ and semi-norm

Tags: functional-analysis

i'm starting of course of functional analysis and i'm struggling to understand how to manipulate the following

> Show that $\lVert f\rVert_{\infty}=\text{Inf} \left\{  M>0,|f(x)| \leq M 
>   \ \mu \ a.e \text{ over } X\right\} $ is a semi-norm over $\mathcal{L}^{\infty}(X,\mathcal{A}, \mu).$

I have no idea how to manipulate this definition.

If you could help me i would greatly appreciate it thanks !

Comment: Hint: notice that the definition of $\|f\|_\infty$ is equivalent to $\|f\|_\inf=\inf\{M>0:\mu(|f|>M)=0\}$. Choosing a monotone decreasing sequence $M_n>0$ such that $\mu(|f|>M_n)=0$ you can see the $m(|f|>\|f\|_\infty)=0$ (use the fact that $\lim_n\mu(A_m)=\mu(A)$ whenever $A_n\nearrow A$). From $\{|f+g|>a+b\}\subset \{|f|>a\}\cup\{|g|>b\}$ you can see that $\|f+g\|_\infty\leq \|f\|_\infty + \|g\|_\infty$

Answer (score 0):

This works fairly directly using the definition.

If $\lambda\in\mathbb C$ is nonzero,
\begin{align}
\|f\|_\infty&=\inf\{M>0:\ |\lambda f|<M\ \text{a.e.}\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\inf\{M>0:\ | f|<M/|\lambda|\ \text{a.e.}\}\\[0.3cm]
&=\inf\{|\lambda|M>0:\ | f|<M\ \text{a.e.}\}\\[0.3cm]
&=|\lambda|\,\|f\|_\infty.
\end{align}
And if $|f|<M$, $|g|<N$ a.e., then $$|f+g|≤|f|+|g|<M+N$$ a.e. Thus $$\|f+g\|_\infty\leq M+N.$$ As this can be done for any such $M$,
$$\|f+g\|_\infty\leq \|f\|_\infty+N.$$ And this works for any $N$ as above so
$$\|f+g\|_\infty\leq \|f\|_\infty+\|g\|_\infty.$$